# reactjs semantic ui Image src not working with backticks example( `${myvalue}` )

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am using semantic-ui-react to style and show some components, and I got stuck into the following issue. Usually, I use backticks, and the dollar signs to use the core values of my variables in a link or HTTP address, but when I try to use it on the Item component, it doesn't work. It only accepts simple or double quotes.
Any ideas how I can do this? I need to dynamically change the src of the Image every time the user presses a new button.

```
 <Item.Image src=`http://...../${this.state.card}`/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes this won't work in react. the correct way to do it is:

```
 <Item.Image src={`http://...../${this.state.card}`} />
```

This is because `(backticks) only work inside Javascript :-)